# In Bootstrap can I create a data-target name on the fly?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Bootstrap and trying to create a unique data-target name for each record in my database.  Can this be done in Bootstrap?

My code looks like this:

```
    $i = 0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        ob_start();

        echo "
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='row features container-fluid'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='well-sm'>
                        <div class='thumbnail'> 
                            <div class='caption'>
                                Name: $tempname</br>

                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-info' 
                                data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#demo[$i]'>
                                click for details</button>
                                <div id='demo[$i]' class='collapse'>$tempdescription</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ";

        $classdata = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $i++;
        ?>

        <div class="more-less"> 
            <div class="more-block">
                <?php echo $classdata ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
```